# How to implement deeplinks for react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to implement deep links(not sure if this is the correct term) in my react project
what I want to do is this :

1. the admin gets a mail: "this user can't login: http://localhost:3000/admin/customer-profile/b1d4a11f-4f6c-4dc1-98a9-ac0c30486c16"
2. the admin is not logged in
3. the admin clicks the link and is forwarded to the login page
4. the admin enters his login details

(the new part)

5. he is forwarded to /admin/customer-profile/b1d4a11f-4f6c-4dc1-98a9-ac0c30486c16

so in the fifth point the admin is redirected to the page link was for instead of going to the homepage.

Below are some snippets to give more info regarding this:

```js
    <div className="App">
      {ready && <Router basename="/admin">

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/privacypolicy">
            <PrivacyPolicy />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/loginhelp">
            <Help />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/termsconditions">
            <TermsConditions />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/logout">
            <Logout />
          </PrivateRoute>

          <Route path="/">
            <SideBar />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path="/tier-list">
                <TierList />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute path="/privacy-policy">
                <PrivacyPolicy />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute path="/help">
                <Help />
              </PrivateRoute>
            </Switch>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>}
    </div>
```

Below is how PrivateRoute looks like :

```js
  function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }: any) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          userInfo != null ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
```

Any ideas How I shall modify this part to achieve the functionality?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280195/1291121

Comment: @SlavikMeltser onEnter has been deprecated. It says render prop can be used for this functionality but not sure how that needs to be implemented to redirect once the user is logged in

Comment: Change whatever is doing "is forwarded to the login page" to pass the original URL as e.g. a `?next=...` query parameter, and have the login flow heed that.

Comment: @AKX  I've edited the question for more clarity. Please check. Is there a way I should modify this code to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: @Nike Well, you already seem to be pushing a `{from: location}` to the history state, so you should probably read that in the login view and redirect there?

Comment: @AKX I tried to make a state variable and set it in the render function for privateroute. After that I'm trying to render redirect  in the "/" route to that location, but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved the problem. What I did was that I passed a pathName prop to the Login component and then if the user was logged in I redirect him to that page but if not then rendered the login page.